# Catch model objects unchanged in admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have models `Car` and `Seat`, with `Seat` having a foreign key to `Car`.

In models.py:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    # ...

class Seat(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    # ...
```

In the admin interface, seats can be added to a car when adding/changing a car (using inline fields).

In admin.py:

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    inlines = [SeatInline]

class SeatInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Seat
    extra = 1
```

When a user adds/changes/deletes a car or adds/changes/delete seats via the `CarAdmin`, I need to log what he did and therefore needs to compare in particular all the seats before and after the change.

The question is:

How to get two lists of seat objects `seats_before` and `seats_after` in order to compare them?  This needs to be done somewhere where I can access `request.user`.

I tried to do that in `save_formset()`, but it did not work.  One of the problems: To get `seats_after`, it is apparently only possible to obtain the list of seats that have been modified, i.e. there is no way to make the difference between an unchanged seat and a deleted seat.

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):

    # ...
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    seats_after = []
    for instance in instances:
        if isinstance(instance, Seat):
            seats_after.append(instance) # Unchanged seats are not added here
    # ...
```

I also have trouble to get `seats_before` in this function.

EDIT:

Following defuz' suggestion, I tried this piece of code:

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):

    car_before = form.save(commit=False)
    seats_before = car_before.seats_set.all()

    form.save_m2m()

    seats_after = []
    for formset in formsets:
        instances = formset.save()
        for instance in instances:
            if isinstance(instance, Seat):
                seats_after.append(instance)
```

In this example there are two problems:

1. `seats_before` seems to contain the new seats instead of the old ones, like if the related objects were saved when the form was saved.
2. `seats_after` contains only changed/added seats.  Unchanged and deleted seats do not appear (and I would like to have the unchanged seats included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ModelAdmin.save_related:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) method.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, for the same reason as when I override save_formset(): unchanged forms do not appear in formsets.

Answer (score 0):

Django signals might be what you're looking for.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/